# Scrolling using x axis scrollbar the tooltip is shown at some other place gnatt highcharts

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

[image: tooltip hover issue]

As soon as I scroll using x axis and hover over any bar the tooltip location comes at the end of the chart rather than above the bar.

```
const chart = Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {
    chart: {  
    spacingLeft: 1,
   style: {
        fontFamily: ' Roboto, sans-serif;'
    },
    // event:{
    //   load: function(e){
    //     console.log(e)
    //   }
    // },
    scrollablePlotArea: {
      scrollPositionY: 0,
      opacity: 0
}
},
  title: {
      text: 'Gantt Chart with Navigation'
  },

//   chart: {
    // scrollablePlotArea: {
    //     minWidth: 700,
    //     scrollPositionX: 1
    // },
//     events: {
//     click: function(event) {
//         alert (
//             'x: '+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', event.xAxis[0].value) +', ' +
//             'y: '+ event.yAxis[0].value
//         );
//     }
// }
//   },

  yAxis: {
      uniqueNames: true,
      grid: {
        enabled: true,
        borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      min: 0,
      max: 6,
      scrollbar:{
          enabled : true
      },
 },

  xAxis: {
    currentDateIndicator: true,
    grid: {
        enabled: true,
        borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
        borderWidth: 1
      }
},

// tooltip: {
//     xDateFormat: '%a %b %d, %H:%M'
// },

  plotOptions:{
    series: {
        pointWidth: 13,
      dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '{point.label}',
          style: {
              cursor: 'default',
              pointerEvents: 'none'
          }
      },
    }
  },

  navigator: {
      enabled: true,
      liveRedraw: 0,
      series: {
          type: 'gantt',
          pointPlacement: 0.5,
          pointPadding: 0.25
      },
      yAxis: {
          min: 0,
          max: 3,
          reversed: true,
          categories: []
      }
  },
  scrollbar: {
      enabled: true
  },
  rangeSelector: {
      enabled: true,
      selected: 5
  },
  
  series: [{
      dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          style: {
                textOutline: 0
            }
        },
        // name : 'vai',
      data:  <?php echo $string; ?> 
  }],
  tooltip: {  
    outside: true,
    useHTML: true,
    style :{
      borderRadius: "10px 10px 10px"
    },
    pointFormatter: customPointFormatter
    }
  });
```

Comment: Hi @user15398154, Could you reproduce the problem in some online code editor? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Comment: as you can see i have added the image in that rather than tooltip coming at the end of chart i want it on the top of bar

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the problem, but I couldn't. So it would be great if you prepare a live example with steps to reporoduce.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0tu879kz/1/         Check the second colomn tooltip     i want the tooltip on the top of the bar

Comment: Thanks for the example. It looks like a Highcharts bug. Please check this workaround: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4cdnuLvf/